# pandas DataFrame to_html style setting

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to print out the pandas DataFrame as html table and send it as email. For Gmail, the styling in header will be eliminated, so the only way I can take is inline styling. The method I am using now is just replacing the html code. For example,

```
styled_html = html_contents.replace('<table ', '<table style="border: 1px solid; text-align:center"')
styled_html = styled_html.replace('<th ', '<th style="background-color:navy; color:white; border:none; padding:5px"')
styled_html = styled_html.replace('<td', '<td style="border:none; padding:5px;"')
```

I wonder if there is a better way for styling the table?
By the way, I have tried `df.style.set_table_styles()`, but it requires further change on the system so I tried not to use.